# Lighting diagrams language and notation

Tags: metadata, diagram, data-exchange

I know, the use case might be specific but more and more stuff in all industry sectors is digitalized—and so is the communication between different departments which sometimes talk in very different languages. I searched the internet, but I wasn't able to find a clear answer (either I didn't find the right search phrases or the internet itself just doesn't know).

Here's my scenario: I'm working with several departments which work with diagrams (for example a lighting setup). This diagram solves different purposes:

- which devices are used?
- where are they placed?
- where are they pointing?
- how are they configured (e.g. exposure)?

They tend to export their finalized diagram as either an image or a PDF— which is fine if you want to print it out but considerably less helpful if another department (mine) has to work with the raw information. That's where I wondered if there's some kind of industry standard (SVG, XML, JSON, etc.) which is both supported by the programs these departments used and can be interpreted by some sort of programming language. Do you know anything like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what is lightning diagram, but for interoperability, machine-readability etc. RDF was designed. Try to find appropriate vocabulary or create it. Then implement convertation from/to RDF :)

Comment: I'm looking for something more graphic. Lightning diagrams are essentially floor plans with the positions of objects and lights. The problem is that most software exports it as pictures which is completely useless. So I need something that works both-ways.

Comment: do you perhaps mean "Lighting" diagrams instead of "Lightning" diagrams, i.e. architectural drawings made by AutoCAD or similar software producing floor plans?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I'm looking for something more graphic. Lightning diagrams are essentially floor plans with the positions of objects and lights. The problem is that most software exports it as pictures which is completely useless. So I need something that works both-ways.

Comment: @HaleemurAli 
Oh, yes, it should have been "Lighting". Thanks for the hint! I'm not that familiar with AutoCAD but if a software can produce floor plans it's at least capable of doing half of the job I want the software in question to do. The question is, can AutoCAD or the particular software in question export to a format that can be interpreted by my web application (so it can't be an image format). Additionally, it'd be good if the format was somewhat standardised.